# When adding a flutter dependencies in terminal, but it showing in terminal "Expected to find project root in current working directory."

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

In my project, When adding a  flutter dependencies in terminal, but it showing in terminal "Expected to find project root in current working directory."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well. But then I noticed I was executing

```
flutter pub get {name_of_package}
```

instead of

```
flutter pub add {name_of_package}
```

use `add` to add a package instead of `get`

flutter pub get {name_of_package} will yeild the following error message:
**Expected to find project root in {name_of_package}.**

Answer (score 2):

You are not in your root directory of the project.

Example:

If your project is in `c:\Projects\MyProject` then make sure you are in this directory before running the command. Also, share the screenshot of the error.